# Display database data in view

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I need to fetch data from database and show in the aspx page.

Below is my code, but it's not working. What's the wrong with them? I have tried to solve this referring everything on the internet. I'm familiar with PHP, but not ASP.net. So it is difficult to figure out the correct solution since I'm new to this.

**Mydefault.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Debug="true" CodeFile="Mydefault.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ccccff">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <h4 style="color: #800080"> Test Page</h4>
     <div>
        <table class="style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="style3" style="color: #800000; font-size: large;">
                Search</td>
                <td class="style2">
                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                 </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Go" onclick="Button1_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <p> 
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" ForeColor="Maroon"></asp:Label>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
        CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" Height="90px" Width="260px">
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" /> 
      </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Mydefault.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public SqlConnection con;
    public string constr;

    public void connection()
    { 
        constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["locations"].ToString();
        con = new SqlConnection(constr);

        con.Open();
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Visible = false;
    }

    private void rep_bind()
    {
        connection();

        string query = "select * from locations where Name like'" + TextBox1.Text + "%'";

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection();
        string query = "select Name  from locations where Name like'" + TextBox1.Text + "%'";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);

        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = com.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            dr.Read();

            rep_bind();
            GridView1.Visible = true;

            TextBox1.Text = "";
            Label1.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            GridView1.Visible = false;        
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "The search Term " + TextBox1.Text + " &nbsp;Is Not Available in the Records"; ;
        }
    }
}
```

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
         <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    </system.web>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="locations" 
             connectionString="server=localhost;database=mylocations;uid=myuser;password=Mypass;" 
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Can you explain what does it means 'not working'? Any error message to share?

Answer (score 0):

You execute the same query two times (rep_bind and button_click) and you never close the connection to the database. This will create many paths to error conditions. For example while a connection is busy serving a DataReader you cannot use it for other tasks. And I bet that this is the point where your program exhibits the first error.
You should not leave a connection open for more time than necessary to fetch your data.

And, of course as already stated in comments, you should use parameters to query a database and never concatenate user inputs to your sql commands.

So first thing to change is the *connection* method

```
public SqlConnection connection()
{ 
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["locations"].ToString();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    con.Open();
    return con;
}
```

Now we return the connection from this method. Why? Because we can use the returned object in a *using* statement that will provide our code the functionality required to close the connection everytime we use it. And as another bonus we don't need anymore two global variables.
In the *rep_bind* method we could write

```
private bool rep_bind()
{
    using(SqlConnection con = connection())
    {
        string query = "select * from locations where Name like @name";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =  TextBox1.Text + "%";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        bool hasRows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0;
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        return hasRows;
   }
}
```

Now at the end of the using block the connection will be closed and destroyed and a variable telling us if we have rows or not is returned to the calling code.
The *button_click* event handler takes care to orchestrate all the backend and the UI interface

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(rep_bind())
    {
        GridView1.Visible = true;
        TextBox1.Text = "";
        Label1.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        GridView1.Visible = false;        
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = "The search Term " + TextBox1.Text + " &nbsp;Is Not Available in the Records"; ;
    }
}
```